# It fails to compile a c++ map structure as map<A, pair<B, C> >

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a code in c++ with stl map with the second parameter defined as a pair

```
int keys[10] = {1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 6};
char s[5];
map< unsigned int, pair<string, int> > tmpMap;

for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  if (tmpMap.find(keys[i])==tmpMap.end())
  {
    sprintf(s, "%i", keys[i]);
    tmpMap.insert(make_pair(keys[i], make_pair(s, 1)));
  }
  else tmpMap[keys[i]].second++;
}

for (map< unsigned int, pair<string, int> >::iterator it=tmpMap.begin();   it!=tmpMap.end(); ++it)
{
cout << (*it).first << "  " << (*it).second << endl;
}
```

But it fail to compile, it said, no match operator <<. But (*it).first and (*it).second are just string and int, why it doesn't work?

Comment: Wouldn't (*it).first be an unsigned int, and (*it).second be pair<string, int>?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not true, `first` is an `unsigned int`, while `second` is a `pair<string,int>` because the iterator of a map doesn't give you directly the pair but the couple key,value.

I guess you should do

```
pair<string,int> pair = (*it).second;
cout << pair.first << "  " << pair.second << endl;
```

Comment: I'm thinking he might want to use the reference of (*it).second, unless performing a copy every time is ok.

Comment: Yes, it's a waste of copy indeed.

Comment: Add `&` to it to avoid copying: `pair<string,int> &pair = (*it).second;`

Comment: Better yet `pair<string,int> &pair = it->second;` which is clearer

Comment: Thank guys. I think I misunderstand the usage of the iterator. I thought it gives the value each time. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your (*it).second is pair , you need to have

```
cout << (*it).first << "  " << (*it).second.first << " " << 
(*it).second.first << endl;
```

This is since when iterating over map, you get pair, then first is the key and second is the value - in your case a pair also.